# Symfony3 - creating a vendor-based bundle

Tags: php, composer-php, bundle, symfony, vendor

We'd like to create a bundle which can deployed via composer/packagist for others to use. It'll wrap the logic created by the owners of MessageBird. Basically a kind of Service which will indeed be called with the container via `ourvendor.messagebird.messaging`.

Since it's a type of bundle (as per the docs of Sf3), we created a bundle while following the documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_bundle.html

As the directory `/src` we used `/vendor` instead. That's when it all went wrong. Our namespace could not be located, loaded or even when we manually added it to the autoloading classes of Composer it failed all the same.

The question is, what is the best practice to go about this? We got it working right now and what we did was the following:

1. We created a bundle wit the following cmd:

   - `bin/console generate:bundle --shared --namespace=OurVendor/MessageBird/MessageBirdBundle --bundle-name=MessageBirdBundle --format=yml`
2. We moved the `/src/OurVendor` directory to `/vendor/OurVendor` as the only way to get a perfect generation was to use the default `/src` folder.
3. We manually updated the AppKernel.php
4. We did some debugging with namespaces for Composer but eventually we added `"OurVendor\\":"vendor/"` to the "autoload/psr-4" directive in root composer.json
5. We ran `composer dumpautoload && bin/console cache:clear -e dev` which resulted in an error.
6. We ran `composer -o update` which checked all dependencies and updated accordingly, including autogenerated autoload files
7. Strangely enough we had to add the Bundle to the `AppKernel.php` class and cleaned the cache again.

After all this it worked but the documentation said no such thing about developing a 3rd party vendor bundle.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

So long story short, did we go about it the wrong way or what?

Comment: to be available in the vendor directory it must be hosted and registered with [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).  Make the bundle in your `src` directory, put it on packagist, then you can `composer require` it wherever you like. But be aware that it will be public. Thats the point of vendor

Comment: Thanks @DevDonkey! Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/vendor` directory is managed by composer. Do not copy/move anything there. Don't even edit anything there, unless you understand all consequences.

When you create a shared bundle, you need to push it to a VCS of your choice, and add it as a dependency in `composer.json` of the project which uses it.

When you run `composer update` it will check-out your bundle into `/vendor` directory and generate correct autoload file.

Please read more [how to use private repositories with composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories).

Comment: You're totally right! Thanks for the help and the clarification.